# Xarmin Live : Unable to deploy on iPhone

Tags: xamarin.ios

I wanted to try Xamarin Live on my iPhone but it is not working at all. I started by creating a new Cross platform project using Xamarin.Forms and Shared projects. Everything is working perfectly with Android but when i'm trying to deploy on iOS, I always add the following error :

```
The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)       C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\App2\App2\App2\App.xaml.cs
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: It is a known issue with ios platform , you could try to access it via Test Flight,https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/95825/ios-run-time-errors-type-or-namespace-name-not-found-with-xamarin-live-player-and-hanselman-forms

Comment: Thanks @ColeXia-MSFT !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use Xamarin Live on iOS, for now, you need to register to the Test Flight program using this page : https://xamarinhq.wufoo.com/forms/live-player-alpha-program-agreement/